# How to redirect to JSP inside WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp with a NAV in it, which further contains and UL with the following elements as shown in the code below,

```
<nav>
     <ul>
        <li class="current"><a>Home</a></li>
        <li><a>Access Control</a></li>
        <li><a>Site Administration</a></li>
        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a>Visitor Management</a></li>
      </ul>                
</nav>
```

What I want to do is to redirect this page to the corresponding jsp page whenever an LI is clicked. Now since all the pages are inside WEB-INF Folder, I cant figure out how to do so. I dont want to create a jsp out side WEB-INF and then put servlet redirection code in it. Thanks in advance.

What can I use here ?

P.S: Started web development few months before. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to invoke a servlet through href on the LI.

In the servlet, you need to use requestdispatcher to redirect to your jsp

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/sample.jsp" );
dispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

=================EDIT : Sample Code =========================================

Index.html

```
<nav>
     <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="/DynamicTest/MyServlet">Home</a></li>
        <li><a>Access Control</a></li>
        <li><a>Site Administration</a></li>
        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a>Visitor Management</a></li>
      </ul>                
</nav>
```

Servlet code

```
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/sample.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Jsp location :

```
WEB-INF/sample.jsp
```

Comment: now to redirect to corresponding page we have to pass arguments in the Servlet URL right ? can you explain that a bit too

Comment: Thank you I have figured it out, thank you very much.Please upvote the post so that newbees can get help. Thanks again :)