# How to link different URLs to different items in forEach loop in JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a `facultylist.jsp` page which displays `List<Faculty>` as a request attribute parameter in forEach loop and I want every item in this loop to be a link to specified faculty `facultyview.jsp`. How can I achieve that ?

*facultylist.jsp:*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Faculties</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Faculties list</h1>
    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="faculty" items="${faculties}">
            <li><a href="???">${faculty.name}</a></li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

*facultyview.jsp:*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Faculty</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${faculty.name}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Faculty name: <c:out value="${requestScope.name}"></c:out></li>
        <li>Total seats: <c:out value="${requestScope.total_seats}"></c:out></li>
        <li>Budget seats: <c:out value="${requestScope.budget_seats}"></c:out></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="faculty?apply">apply for this faculty </a>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if its may help, but I'm using following technologies: tomcat, jsp, servlets and log4j.In my project I have one FrontController, which is a servlet that interacts with Command pattern - each Command returns a path to resource and action type: forward or redirect.

Comment: where are those URL? can't you make a faculty.url field???

Comment: <li><a href="${faculty.url}">${faculty.name}</a></li> should work

Comment: Are the URLs really different, or can you have the same URL and have the faculty as a parameter concatenated to the URL?

Comment: are you trying to pass list of faculty.links  like names and use smth like `<li><a href="${faculty.links}">${faculty.name}</a></li>`?

Comment: @JordiCastilla faculty represents an entity from database, i'm not sure if I want to change it adding another field, or you mean some other way ?

Comment: @Jango but `${faculty.url}` means that I have a field in faculty, which is not true

Comment: check my answer's edit, but since i'm not sure how you get the URL's, I can't help more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your issue by adding a query params to the link, edit with respect to the comment. Note that you cannot access directly the JSP pages that reside under *WEB-INF* folder. Also, to encode properly the paramters, better construct url like

```
<c:url value="facultyview.jsp" var="url">
  <c:param name="name" value="${faculty.name}"/>
  <c:param name="total_seats" value="${faculty.total_seats}"/>
  <c:param name="budget_seats" value="${faculty.budget_seats}"/>
</c:url>
<li><a href="${url}">${faculty.name}</a></li>
```

and than than in your *facultyview.jsp* read from the query params

```
<li>Faculty name: ${param.name}</li>
<li>Total seats: ${param.total_seats}</li>
<li>Budget seats:${param.budget_seats}</li>
```

This direct JSP communication should solve your immediate issue, but a truly proper way would be to pass an *id* of a *faculty* to servlet, fetch the *faculty* instance, place in the model and pass to the view.

Comment: i have tried your solution, but I get the `HTTP Status 404 Error`. The URL that I'm forwarding is as example: `http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF/view/client/faculty/view.jsp?name=faculty of applied mathematics&total_seats=20&budget_seats=10`

Comment: I've edited the response, the main issue is that you can't directly access a page under /WEB-INF so you'll either have to move the jsp, or forward to it

Comment: oh thank you for practice advice! but as I know for now the only way to get info from servlet is to use <form> tags. And they are not working with `<ul><li>` tags as I know. So my question is should I replace in `facultyview.jsp` `<ul><li>` tags with `<form>` and use it like:
`<form id="facultiesList" method="GET" action="frontcontroller"> 
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="viewFaculty">`
 or there is another way ?

Comment: is this approach the same ?
`<jsp:forward page="/WEB-INF/view/client/faculty/view.jsp">
<jsp:param name="name" value="${faculty.name}"/>
<jsp:param name="total_seats" value="${faculty.total_seats}"/>
<jsp:param name="budget_seats" value="${faculty.budget_seats}"/>
</jsp:forward>`

Comment: no need for form, the link inside your  a tag can hit a servlet e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907482/call-a-servlet-on-click-of-hyperlink, and from the servlet, its perfectly OK to forward to a jsp page that resides in WEB-INF, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928427/how-to-redirect-to-jsp-inside-web-inf-folder. The work inside your servlet is to collect the parameters, and either append them when forwarding to jsp, or adding them into a request scope, in which case your original facultyview page will work well also

Comment: regarding forward, you can't do jsp forward when clicking on a link, so either use servlets, or place your jsp outside of WEB-INF folder so that it can be accessed directly (via link)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69197/discussion-between-mark-and-master-slave).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field in Faculty entity simply:

```
<a href="${faculty.url}">${faculty.name}</a>
```

> @Mark: faculty represents an entity from database, i'm not sure if I want to change it adding another field, or you mean some other way ?

Add a field does not means you must change database, you can have a Helper entity that inherits from `Faculty` and have more fields you can need,

```
public class FacultyFormHelper extends Faculty implements Serializable {

    private String URL;
```

and in your view:

```
<a href="${facultyHelper.url}">${facultyHelper.name}</a>
```

But, If you don't want to modify your database, either create a helper class, you may add `onclick` event to the `<a>`

```
<a onclick="goToURL(${faculty.id})">
```

Then retrieve the data... ***i'm not sure how you get the urls...*** from a variable in the view, ajax call or wherever you have this URL...

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I'm a starter, so may I ask you  for the future if this is a good practice to extend entity functionality in children and use them in jsp's ?

Comment: As far as I know (I'm not an expert either) it is a good and usual practice, Also you must check how to implement an entity populator or use a framework like `dozer` to manage your database / model / view entities...

Answer (score 0):

in other  way is just take the selected value from the drop down with a name and forward it to front controller servlet ,there use if else conditions and depends on the value you could forward the request to corresponding jsp or servlet

```
<select name="value"> in jsp 

String value=req.getParameter("value");   in servlet

if()
else if()
```